# jQuery: issue with converting text to integer (input value)

Tags: jquery, string, numbers, number-formatting

I am using the following code on a page from me where I cant figure out how the switch can recognise this as a number as it always fails.

My value is a standard integer that varies and the code works fine if I hard-code it but not when I just it to the variable. I tried parseInt as well. I always get the result for < 1 as it reads my number as text / 0. 
The input value is filled in with PHP.

I hope someone here can help me with this.

**My input field:**

```
<input type="hidden" class="span12" id="daysRest" name="daysRest" value="40" />
```

**The code where I want to use it:**

```
daysRest = $('#daysRest').val();

            switch(true) 
            {
                case(daysRest < -999):
                    bulletColor = 'white';
                    daysResttxt = '';
                    break;
                case(daysRest < 0):
                    bulletColor = 'red';
                    daysResttxt = daysRest + ' days remaining';
                    break;
                case(daysRest < 1):
                    bulletColor = 'red';
                    daysResttxt = 'less than 1 day remaining';
                    break;
                case(daysRest < 4):
                    bulletColor = 'yellow';
                    daysResttxt = daysRest + ' BD remaining';
                    break;
                default:
                    bulletColor = 'white';
                    daysResttxt = '';
                    break;
            }

            $('#daysRest').val(daysRest);
            $('#spanRest').text(daysResttxt);
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed a foreach loop in PHP and so i moved all the above there - works fine now. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to parse string to integer. use `parseInt()`. it will parse string to integer.

replace this:

```
daysRest = $('#daysRest').val();
```

by

```
daysRest = parseInt($('#daysRest').val());
```

[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/59/)

Comment: The return of `parseInt` it's a `NaN`?

Comment: @RagenDazs: Thats exactly what I have and why it returns the wrong colour for me as it doesnt recognise the number here. Is there a way i can rewrite the switch to make this work ?

Comment: parseInt doesn't return 0 when use pass empty string - you can debug with `alert($('#daysRest').val() + ' - ' + parseInt($('#daysRest').val()));` after all you can use any other debuger. That's because `parseInt(''); // will result NaN`

Comment: Ok but NaN is the same issue for me then.